# If statement syntax error (shell)

Tags: shell, if-statement

```
if [[ ! -z grep echo "${prof}" | cut -d. -f1 dm_smear.dat ]]
```

This gives me the following error. I am trying to find a string `${prof}` in a file `dm_smear.dat` and if that exists in the file I will do certain operations

```
: syntax error in conditional expression   
: syntax error near `1`'   
: `         if [[ ! -z grep `echo "${prof}" | cut -d . -f 1` dm_smear.dat ]]'
```

Comment: What does the variable `${prof}` contain? Given the amount if syntax errors and misconceptions in this short piece of code, you'd probably better explain *exactly* what should happen instead of have us guess.

Comment: An `if` statement is not a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to find a string ${prof} in a file dm_smear.dat and if
>   that exists in the file I will do certain operations

You can simply use the `-q` option for `grep`.  Say:

```
if grep -q "${prof}" dm_smear.dat; then
   echo "Found the string"
   # Do something here
fi
```

---

You could fix your original code by using process substitution correctly:

```
if [[ ! -z $(grep $(echo "${prof}" | cut -d . -f 1) dm_smear.dat) ]];
   echo "Found the string"
   # Do something here
fi
```

Comment: That just makes it quiet, still the loop doesn't run.

I also tried 
 if [[ ! -z cat dm_smear.dat | grep `echo "${prof}" | cut -d. -f1` ]]
 but same error followed.

Comment: @Devansh Why are you executing: `if [[ ! -z cat dm_smear.dat | grep echo "${prof}" | cut -d. -f1 ]]; `?  Did you even try what was suggested in the answer?

Comment: Yes, I did! The loop doesn't run.

I did it with and without -q
with -q : loop doesn't run
without -q gives the same error

Comment: @Devansh If `grep` doesn't find the string `${prof}` in the file `dm_smear.dat` then the loop won't run.  Isn't that what you wanted?  Maybe you should update the question to clarify further if that isn't the case.

Comment: Yes, this is what exactly I want, but I've checked and string ${prof} exits in the file dm_smear.dat.

Comment: @Devansh See edit above for an alternative that fixes what you were attempting.

Comment: the problem was caused by 'cut', I removed it, modified dm_smear.dat, it works now.

Comment: If `${prof}` contains regex specials, you need to use `grep -F` or escape them properly.  Also look at `${prof%%.*}` for dropping everything from the first dot from the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code

prof="KEY1"

if ! [ -z `cut -d. -f1 dm_smear.dat | grep ${prof}` ] ; then

```
     echo "FOUND"
```

else

```
     echo "NOT FOUND"
```

fi

In above code, we are searching KEY1 in dm_smear.dat file at first column

the output will be FOUND if file contains KEY1 in first column of any line, otherwise it prints NOT FOUND

where dm_smear.dat contains

KEY1.VALUE1

KEY2.VALUE2

KEY3.VALUE2